# Deriving the $Var(X) = E(X^2) - \mu^2$ from the moment around the mean formula.

Tags: expected-value, variance

I want to be able to derive  $Var(X) = E(X^2) - \mu^2$  from the moment around the mean formula $Var(X) = E((X-\mu)^2)$. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expand $(X-\mu)^2$ , and use the fact that $E[X] = \mu$.

Comment: I am unsure how $X^2 - 2\mu X + \mu^2$ will help? Did I expand incorrectly? @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг

Comment: Take the expectation of this value . Use linearity of expectation, and the fact that $\mu$ is a constant so comes out of the expectation.

Comment: Thank you so much, I see it now.

Comment: Great. Kindly write an answer and accept it yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

Please find the solution, let me know if you have questions.

Comment: [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), please.